# How to add tagged text to an element from a simple string?

Tags: python, xml, lxml

With python lxml, I want to generate an etree.Element whose content is taken from a string. I have two cases:

1. It is a simple string (ex: "Hello world!").
2. It is a tagged string, but still, for python it is a string and I do not know in advance that it's a tagged one (ex: "Hello <value-of select=\"world\"/>!").

How to handle the second case?

Here is a naive, not functioning way:

```py
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> string = "Hello <value-of select=\"world\"/>!"
>>> xml = etree.Element('root')
>>> xml.text = string
>>> etree.tostring(xml)
... b'<root>Hello &lt;value-of select="world"/&gt;!</root>'
```

I am well aware that, if I know the structure of my string, I have to use the tail method of etree.Element as described in [the lxml tutorial](https://lxml.de/tutorial.html). So here is a functioning, not generalizable way:

```py
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> xml2 = etree.Element('root')
>>> xml2.text = "Hello "
>>> valueof = etree.SubElement(xml2, 'value-of')
>>> valueof.set('select', 'world')
>>> valueof.tail = '!'
>>> etree.tostring(xml2)
... b'<root>Hello <value-of select="world"/>!</root>'
```

But how to do this automatically without knowing in advance the exact string?

I do not know how to parse the string so that I can split its parts. Or maybe I should try another way.

I tried this:

```py
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> string="Hello <value-of select=\"world\"/>!"
>>> tree = etree.parse(StringIO(string))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "src/lxml/lxml.etree.pyx", line 3427, in lxml.etree.parse (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:81117)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1828, in lxml.etree._parseDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:118072)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1848, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:118341)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1729, in lxml.etree._parseDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:116899)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1063, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseUnicodeDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:110886)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 595, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:105109)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 706, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:106817)
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 635, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError (src/lxml/lxml.etree.c:105671)
  File "<string>", line 1
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1
```

But since etree.parse requires a well formed xml and there is no root element, it fails. So I tried this, hoping it would be less strict:

```py
>>> tree = etree.parse(StringIO(string), etree.XMLParser(recover=True))
>>> etree.tostring(tree)
```

but the output is empty, so it seems I cannot parse my string in order to add the resulting tree to the existing one... Which is the way I need to do things, because I compose my xml from scratch.

Back to my question: how to handle the 2 cases I presented earlier?

Comment: `etree.parse` requires well-formed XML. `Hello <value-of select=\"world\"/>!` is not well-formed since there is no root element.

Comment: @mzjn absolutely, that is why I tried with "recover=True" but it doesn't work as I thought. I clarified my question on this regard. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap the string (simple or tagged) in a root element to make it well-formed XML.

```
from lxml import etree

simple = "Hello world!"
tagged = "Hello <value-of select=\"world\"/>!"

xml1 = "<root>" + simple + "</root>"
xml2 = "<root>" + tagged + "</root>"

# fromstring() returns an Element object 
elem1 = etree.fromstring(xml1) 
elem2 = etree.fromstring(xml2)
```